# Propel uncaught error "Class not found "

Tags: php, smarty, propel

I am getting this Uncaught error while calling one of the classes in propel

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Archivedb\Archivedb\AbstractQuery' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\archivedb\articlesOverview.php:37

The reason I am surprised to see is, it actually exits like all other classes that I am calling.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

use Archivedb\Archivedb\AbstractQuery;
use Archivedb\Archivedb\ArticleQuery;
use Archivedb\Archivedb\TypeofarticleQuery;

require_once 'conf/config.php';
require_once 'default.php';

 if( !empty($_GET['magid'] && $_GET['year'] && $_GET['issue'] && 
  $_GET['magName'])){

   $magazineId = $_GET['magid'];
   $year = $_GET['year'];
   $issue = $_GET['issue'];

   $articlesArray = array();
   $articles = ArticleQuery::create()
   ->filterByMagazineId( $magazineId )
   ->filterByYear($year)
   ->distinct()
   ->filterByIssue($issue)
   ->find();

    foreach ($articles as $article) {
    $articlesArray[] = $article->toArray();
    }
   }

   $typeofarticlesArray = array();
   $types = TypeofarticleQuery::create()
   ->find();

   foreach ($types as $type) {
   $typeofarticlesArray[] = $type->toArray();
   }

   $abstract = AbstractQuery::create()
   ->filterByMagazineId($magazineId)
   ->filterByYear($year)
   ->distinct()
   ->filterByIssue($issue)
   ->find();

   $smarty->assign('issueAbstract', $abstract->getIssueAbstract());
   $smarty->assign('magazineName', $_GET['magName']);
   $smarty->assign('magid', $magazineId);
   $smarty->assign('types', $typeofarticlesArray);
   $smarty->assign('year', $year);
   $smarty->assign('issue', $issue);
   $smarty->assign('articles', $articlesArray);
   $smarty->display('views/allArticlesOverview.tpl');
```

In here all classes are called and are working properly except the AbstractQuery class.
I recently changed my schema.xml to add this new table, and i have done before with other tables, but never encountered this problem.
Can anyone spot, what the problem is?

and here is my table in the schema.xml :

```
<table name="abstract" idMethod="native" phpName="Abstract" nameSpace="Archivedb">
        <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
        <column name="issue_abstract" phpName="IssueAbstract" type="LONGVARCHAR" />
        <column name="year" phpName="Year" type="INTEGER" size="11" />
        <column name="issue" phpName="Issue" type="VARCHAR" size="255" />
        <column name="magazine_id" phpName="MagazineId" type="INTEGER" size="11" />


        <foreign-key foreignTable="magazine" name="fk_abstract_magazine1" onDelete="none" onUpdate="none">
                <reference local="magazine_id" foreign="id"/>
        </foreign-key>

        <vendor type="mysql">
          <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
          <parameter name="Charset" value="utf8mb4"/><parameter name="Collate" value="utf8mb4_general_ci"/>
        </vendor>
    </table>
```

Comment: The php code refers to `AbstractQuery`, but in the xml the name is `Abstract`

Comment: The table name is abstract, which you can see in the schema, what propel does is, it creates two classes, namely in this case, **Abstract.php** and **AbstractQuery.php** . where all the getters and setters are stored.
So AbstractQuery class is being used here to query  the required item in the database.

Comment: There are some missing pieces here, so I can't post an answer.  Your code looks good.  When you edited schema.xml, did you also generate the model classes (Abstract.php, AbstractQuery.php, AbstractTableMap.php, etc.).  If so, do those exist where you expect them to be?